# How to find the permission level of Google Adwords developer token

Tags: google-ads-api

We have applied for developer token in 2013 and have been using it to call all Google Adwords APIs [v201809]. Recently we have decided to add a new feature which requires a different Adwords API (TargetingIdeaService).

We are not sure what permission access level (https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/access-levels#permissible_use) our developer token has and whether we can use our existing token to call this API feature.

Any idea how to find that out?